# Node.js mongodb set default safe variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run a Node.js script locally and it's giving me this error message:

> ```
> ========================================================================================
> =  Please ensure that you set the default safe variable to one of the                  =
> =   allowed values of [true | false | {j:true} | {w:n, wtimeout:n} | {fsync:true}]     =
> =   the default value is false which means the driver receives does not                =
> =   return the information of the success/error of the insert/update/remove            =
> =                                                                                      =
> =   ex: new Db(new Server('localhost', 27017), {safe:false})                           =
> =                                                                                      =
> =   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command                           =
> =                                                                                      =
> =  The default of false will change to true in the near future                         =
> =                                                                                      =
> =  This message will disappear when the default safe is set on the driver Db           =
> ========================================================================================
> ```

Here are my variables:

```
var express = require('express');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore;
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var db = new Db(Config.dbName, new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}), {});    

var HttpGet = require('./httpGet').HttpGet;
var URL = require('url');

var dbClient = null; // this is initialized when db is opened
var app = module.exports = express();
```

The same scripts runs fine on my live server. It only complanes when I run it locally.

I found this same issue being discussed on github but found no solution. 
https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/issues/77

Anyone know what could cause this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following works for me using the 1.1.11 mongo driver:

```
var db = new Db(Config.dbName, new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}), {safe: true});
```

Without the `{safe: true}` parameter I do get the same warning as you show in your question.

This warning was a very recent addition to the driver; you're probably using an older version of the driver on your server which is why you don't see the warning there.

Comment: I have tried that, When I do this, I get "Running
ERROR: (Thu Oct 11 2012 15:36:44 GMT-0400 (EDT)): {}". It does not tell me what the error is.

Comment: @FarhanAhmad Have you run it under the debugger to see which line is generating that error?

Comment: Same thing. It start listening on port 5858 and then shows "Running
ERROR: (Thu Oct 11 2012 15:57:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)): {}"

Comment: @FarhanAhmad Start your app with with the `--debug-brk` node command line option so that you can step through it.

Comment: You can also set it to false. The driver just wants you to set it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it to work by setting the strict mode to false. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I got it to work by setting the `strict` mode to false.

```
var db = new Db(config.dbName, new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}), {safe: false, strict: false});
```

Comment: Never mind, it did work. I was looking in the wrong place ;-)

Comment: I just pasted the exact code shown by Farhan above and I am still getting the message. I am using 1.3.23 of the mongoDb node.js driver. Also tried KiranYNG's code. The warning isn't a show stopper but it bothers me that it says it will go away if you set the write concern options but then it doesn't go away!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
var db = new Db((new DbServer('127.0.0.1', 27017), {w:-2,journal:false,fsync:false,safe: false})
```