# annoying message when use mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using this code in order to use mongodb:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new mongo.Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, safe: true});
var db = new mongo.Db('dbname', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'dbname' database");
        db.collection("items", {safe:true}, function(err, collection) {
            console.log("Open database");
            if (err) {
                console.log("The 'items' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data.");
                var items = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    items.push({
                        title: "title" + i,
                        site_name: "site_name" + i,
                        url: "url" + i,
                        type: "type" + i,
                        image: "image" + i
                    });
                }
                db.collection("items", function(err, collection) {
                    collection.insert(items, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I ran the application I get the message:

```
========================================================================================
=  Please ensure that you set the default write concern for the database by setting    =
=   one of the options                                                                 =
=                                                                                      =
=     w: (value of > -1 or the string 'majority'), where < 1 means                     =
=        no write acknowlegement                                                       =
=     journal: true/false, wait for flush to journal before acknowlegement             =
=     fsync: true/false, wait for flush to file system before acknowlegement           =
=                                                                                      =
=  For backward compatibility safe is still supported and                              =
=   allows values of [true | false | {j:true} | {w:n, wtimeout:n} | {fsync:true}]      =
=   the default value is false which means the driver receives does not                =
=   return the information of the success/error of the insert/update/remove            =
=                                                                                      =
=   ex: new Db(new Server('localhost', 27017), {safe:false})                           =
=                                                                                      =
=   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command                           =
=                                                                                      =
=  The default of no acknowlegement will change in the very near future                =
=                                                                                      =
=  This message will disappear when the default safe is set on the driver Db           =
========================================================================================
```

What is this message and how can I fix it?
Is there any better way to use mongodb?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The docs are available at

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/

use the MongoClient interface instead

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

Comment: lead here getting the same error, pointing to documentation in my situation is not very helpful.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846238/node-js-mongodb-set-default-safe-variable

Answer (score 8):

MongoDB is helpfully instructing you to set default write concern (w) parameter in it's DB settings.

Changing this line should do the trick

```
   var db = new mongo.Db('dbname', server, {w:1});
```

This will be fine for development/hacking, but you should understand the ramifications of this option before going to production.

[MongoDB Write Concern Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/)

Answer (score 3):

Db constructor has three arguments. "DataBaseName", ServerObject, {parameters}.

The message displayed is a warning about the write concern and explains the options you got.

```
 var _mongodb = 'MyDataBase';
 var db = new mongodb.Db(_mongodb, server, {w:'majority'});
```

Reference: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html

Answer (score 1):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
db = mongoClient.db("mydb");
db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
         console.log("Connected to 'mydb' database");
         db.collection('mycollection', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
        if (err) {
                console.log("error...");

        }
    });
}
});
```

Ref: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html